# Ionic 2 development debug with vscode

Tags: angular, debugging, ionic2, visual-studio-code

Currently I use and see a lot of `console.log()` statements in dev code and was wondering what would be the best approach to get a concise debug workflow, with breakpoints, inspection etc using visual studio code, specifically for angular 2 and ionic 2 development.

So in the example below i want to replace `console.log('Program Page:',this.pageDetails);` with a simple breakpoint that is hit, that then shows debug information in the vsc debug side panel. Like you would do in visual studio's debug build process

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Free Variant:**
Well the best debug Workflow for me is to use Firefox and Visual Studio Code.
With VSC you can set Breakpoints and with Chrome you get all you need: Inspect, Console Output and Network Requests. Chrome also provides Chrome Inspect and with this tool you can debug on your native Device

**Payed Variant:**
In this Variant I suggest you to use Webstorm. It costs a little bit of money but with Webstorm youll get the best debug workflow. Webstorm also provides a Console Box so you wont need to use Chrome. You can plugin your Device and youll get the console logs from your native Device in Webstorm. 
https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/download/

**EDIT:**

If your Breakpoints doesnt get fired it could have different reasons.
1. Make sure you didnt opened your Project in multible Editors
2. Make sure you didnt debug your Project in multible Browsers (Chrome/Firefox)
3. If both Solutions dont work try to setup your Project for Breakpoints. Here is a Tutorial:
http://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20161122-DebuggingIonic2AppsInChromeFromVisualStudioCode.html

Comment: I have tried setting breakpoints in vsc but they never get hit.

Comment: Please Update your Question with a Screenshot where you set your Breakpoints.

Comment: aah ... how would that help? i set my breakpoints in the code.

Comment: because Visual Studio sometimes have a bug that your Breakpoints arent gona fire if you set them wrong

Comment: In example mostly of the time breakpoints arent gonna fire if you set them at a function name or set them at a "{" for example

Comment: How do you "set them wrong" ? Do you mean in the configuration setup?

Comment: I mean the red point/dot you set on the left side of the code.

Comment: No i am setting them on variable names. Just trying to recreate basic console log with debug .. will update my question though